# simple ruby plugin/extension architecture

Tags: ruby, scripting, plugins

I'm currently writing a little program, that watches a directory and adds video files to a conversion queue. I've been able to achieve that (using resque).

But before adding the to the conversion queue I want to trigger specific actions based on the filename.

E.g:

- drop (don't add to queue) specific files according to filename
- rename files
- copy certain files

Therefore I want to run a couple of helpers before the adding takes place. I want them executed in a certain order and I want it to be easy to add other helpers.

The way I thought about it would then look like this:

Every helper is a ruby class with a set of methods:

- run (executes the helper)
- new_name (returns the new filename if it changed)
- stop (prevents following helpers to run and prevents adding to the
  queue)

All helpers should be stored in one directory and will be run in alphabetical order (ext/00_helper1.rb, ext/01_helper2.rb...).

pseudocode would look like this:

```
filename = <parameter>
stop = false

for each file in ext/*.rb
 obj = asClass(file).new_instance(filename)
 obj.run
 if (obj.new_name) filename = obj.new_name
 if (obj.stop) 
  stop = true 
  break
 end
end

if not stop add_to_queue(filename)
```

So my question is:

is there an elegant ruby way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head I can say that a possible way would be to have a global array of Proc/lambda objects which each file appends to. So an example of a helper file would be:

```
$helpers << Proc.new do |filename|
  case filename
    when /.foo$/ then :stop
    when /.bar$/ then filename.sub(/.bar$/, '.baz') # and presumably rename the actual file as well ...
  end
end
```

And then your main file would be something like:

```
$helpers = []

filename = <parameter>
stop = false

Dir.new(<helperdir>).entries.each do |name|
  require name
  result = $helpers.last.call(name)
  if result == :stop
    stop = true
    break
  end
  # using respond_to? :to_s would probably be better, but in this example :stop would match this criteria as well as strings
  filename = result if result.is_a? String
end
```

I haven't tested any of this, but hopefully you can get the general idea. I've also got no idea how fluent you are at Ruby, so if you don't understand the syntax I'm using please just say so.

Comment: Yes I get the idea. However I wonder if that is thread safe. Writing in  a global variable doesn't sound like a good idea when multiple threads start the conversion at once.